# ui-router state change unwanted delay

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router

When changing between two (not necessary nested) states with ui-router a short delay occurs.
So the new view appears but the old view disappears after about 1 second.

Example code from my `$stateProvider` files:

```
.state('termsofuse',{
    url: '/termsofuse',
    views: {
        'header': {templateUrl: 'res/angular/views/start/part_start_header.html'},
        'main': {templateUrl: 'res/angular/views/other/part_termsofuse_main.html'},
        'footer': {templateUrl: 'res/angular/views/start/part_start_footer.html'}
    }
})

.state('dataprivacy',{
    url: '/dataprivacy',
    views: {
        'header': {templateUrl: 'res/angular/views/start/part_start_header.html'},
        'main': {templateUrl: 'res/angular/views/other/part_dataprivacy_main.html'},
        'footer': {templateUrl: 'res/angular/views/start/part_start_footer.html'}
    }
})
```

There aren't any peaks on my browsers (safari, chrome) cpu usage.
And the error also occurs when the view is already cached.
There aren't any additional settings for ui-router.

Do you know any reasons why this delay could occur?

Comment: Is there any animation CSS that applies to the views?

Comment: no, not yet - first i want a working standard transition